# The rate at which the vector force is acting

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

If $r$ is a position vector of a particle $P$ of mass $0.4$ kg at time $t$, where 
$r = t^3i + t^2 j + t^4k$,
how do I find the rate at which the force acting on $P$ is working at time $t$?

I worked out its velocity, acceleration and KE at $t$. But the rate is Power? If it is Power, it should be Force $\times$ Velocity and I don't know the force in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: It's simply asking $F.v$ To get that, all you need to do is $F=ma$ and scalar multiply with $v$. Mass will be constant

Comment: I got it. There is a second approach too. Power = Work/Time as I have no external forces of resistance in this question.Work = Kinetic Energy. (from this source: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relationship-between-work-done-and-kinetic-energy) therefore I just divide my KE by t.

Comment: Please note. Its work = ∆KE (WORK ENERGY THEOREM). Its talking about change in kinetic energy.@NatD